# Changing the default file to be loaded using lite-server

Tags: node.js, browser-sync, lite-server

How can I change the configurations to load a custom file using lite-server "browserSync" like "about.html" instead of the default one "index.html"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `startPath` [option](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-startPath) and dictate your `about.html` file instead. The easiest way to do this is to create a `bs-config.json` file in the root of your project. This will be *automatically* read and override the defaults for Lite-Server when it is ran. Here is the only thing you would need inside of `bs-config.json` file:

{
  "startPath": "about.html"
}

I have used this very configuration and it works successfully. Keep in mind that if `about.html` is not in the same directory as the configuration file, make sure you specify it's path properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change the configuration to load your custom file just add /about.html after the URL because by default just URL will load your index.html file.